How does recycler view work. Which function is called when and I have less clarity in OnCreateViewHolder() syntax in Kotlin
How does recycler view work? Which function is called when? I have less clarity in OnCreateViewHolder() syntax  in Kotlin
I tried to code it using youtube tutorial still i cannot see through what people in YT explains. It feels so blunt.

FWIW, I cover RecyclerView in this chapter of this free book.

In a class extending RecyclerView.Adapter, the three main functions to override are:

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
override fun getItemCount(): Int

The 1. will be called once for each ViewHolder in the RecyclerView and the number of ViewHolders is limited (an depends on device screen size and some other factors) which the RecyclerView re-uses and hence it's name is RecyclerView. In this, you create an instance of your ViewHolder class which you can access later to update the ui of associated item view.
The 2. will be called again and again whenever a ViewHolder is being used or re-used. It is expected that you update your item view's content here.
The 3. will be called to get how many total items are there in your list so that RecyclerView can show them properly using above two overridden functions.
Even though RecyclerView is efficient already, you can optimize it's performance even more by using a ListAdapter or DiffUtil. Both of these allow partial update (only things that have changed) of the items instead of updating the entire item. Also, this runs or can be done off the main thread and then pass the diffed-list with payloads to adapter on main thread.

@Sleepy Coder, as you are a new contributor to SO, I want to let you know that you can accept the answer if it was useful or working answer for your problem.
